# NPM package is undefined when entirely imported but works fine when destructured

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, import

Im having this strange problem where importing the textile/hub package in node then destructuring it later the program gives an error, but when I destructure while importing the code doesn't error at all. Does anyone know why this is happening, destructuring while importing works fine for the program but I'm still curious.

```
import textileHub from '@textile/hub';
const { Client, ThreadID, PrivateKey } = textileHub;
// This fails saying that textileHub is undefined


import { Client, ThreadID, PrivateKey } from '@textile/hub';
// this works perfectly
```

Answer (score 7):

Those two import syntaxes aren't equivalent- the first one will assign whatever the "default" export from the package is to the variable textileHub. If there isn't a default export (which would have been exported with the syntax `export default value`), your textileHub variable will be undefined.

The second version directly imports those three named imports. The equivalent "get all named imports as one object before destructuring later" syntax would be

```
   import * as textileHub from '@textile/hub';
   const { Client, ThreadID, PrivateKey } = textileHub;
```